# Merge query string with ngRoute

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngroute, angularjs-ng-route

Is it possible to merge query string from the original URL?

So I have this index.html which routes with `ngRoute`, something like this:

```
function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .otherwise(
      redirectTo: '/login'
    )
}
```

What I want to do is to merge the following URL

`index.html?toke=1234567`

to

`index.html#/login?token=1234567`

Comment: Did you mean to say you wanted to get the value of queryString from url `index.html#/login?token=1234567`?

Comment: No. I know it can be done by `$location.search`, what I want is to set up the `$routeProvider` so it would transfer the original URL into the new one.

Answer (score 0):

you can d something like this:

```
.run(["$rootScope", "$location", function($rootScope, $location){
$rootScope.path = {
        key: 'token',
        redirect: function(path, params) {
            var queryParams = {}; 
            queryParams[this.key] = Date.now();
            queryParams["device"] = $location.search().device;
            var location = $location.path(path).search(queryParams);
        }
    };
```

Comment: @lastr2d2: hope it helped you